# Is there a way of selectively including code when publishing in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm writing MATLAB code in order to publish it later. By publishing, I mean the built-in MATLAB `publish` tool that allows the programmer to make a full report generated from their MATLAB code. There's an option to include the code with this report, section by section, preceding the results of this code. Is there a way to tell MATLAB to include some of this code in the report but not all of it? I know there are quite a few markup code tags, but I wasn't able to find anything on this topic.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, I want *all* results to be published, but only *some* of the code. So simply removing this code is not an option.

Cheers! = )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hide your code that you don't want people to see in a script.  For example, in the "sine_wave" example from the `publish` documentation page, I added a single line:

```
junk
```

Here's the content of junk:

```
figure()
plot(0:0.01:6,sin(0:0.01:6))
```

Now run your main script, and the published result has "junk" in the listing, but the contents of junk are not included, and you get the nice version of a sine wave, instead of the crappy one included in their example.

Comment: I guess this is the neatest hack possible.

Comment: why sadly? Indirection is a great programmer's tool in many circumstances.

Comment: @Jason, because now I have to maintain multiple files, instead of a single file.  That is all, I agree, I really like the indirection aspect of my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to do this is to remove the code that you don't want to appear in the output. If you just want to display the code and not the output, then you can just set the `evalCode` property to `false` in your call to `publish`.

If you do want the code to be evaluated, and the output to be published as well, then it's just slightly more complicated.  You can manually execute the parts of the script that you don't want to publish, then publish the code that you care about (by putting it in it's own `.m` file).  It shouldn't matter if the published code depends on any variables that are initialized in the omitted code, since those variables were added to your workspace when you manually executed the omitted code fragments.

**Edit:**

Since you've clarified your question to state that you're interested in publishing some of the code, but all of the output, I would think that your best bet is to just modify the "temporary" script (which contains the partial set of code that you wish to publish) to include any `fprintf`, `disp`, etc. function calls that you want to have appear in the output.

It's a bit hack-ish, but like I said, I'm not aware of any way to get that kind of fine granularity with "annotations" or using the `publish` command.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample script that you can save and [publish](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/publishing-matlab-code.html) which will illustrate one workaround. You first have to set the [**Include code** option](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/specifying-output-preferences-for-publishing.html#bthbe__-3) to `false`, which stops *all* evaluated code from appearing, but you can still display code using a [syntax highlighted code sample](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#bs_uwzr):

```
%% Controlling what code gets published
% Here's how you can do it...

%% Showing results without code
% If you set the
% <https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/specifying-output-preferences-for-publishing.html#bthbe__-3
% *Include code* option> to |false|, you will see the plot but not the code
% that made it:

surf(peaks);  % I'm John Cena!

%% But what if you want some of the code to show?
% The *Include code* setting affects the whole document, so all evaluated
% code will be hidden. If you want some code to show, you can use
% <https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#bs_uwzr
% syntax highlighted sample code>. This does mean you have to have duplicate
% sections of code (one is evaluated, one is displayed), but it's the best
% option thus far:

%%
%
%   surf(peaks);
%

surf(peaks);  % You can't see me, but you see the above!
```

And here's the published output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I change the Matlab expression in the publishing options to

```
myFunction('PUBLISHING');
```

And the first lines of the function code to check for that input, so I can modify my code to only do certain things when publishing, usually displaying figures etc., but not during normal operation. Or vice versa :)

```
function [outputs] = myFunction(input1, input2)

  isPublishing = (nargin == 1) && strcmp(input1, 'PUBLISHING');

  if (nargin == 0) || isPublishing

     % Set up default values
     input1 = 'Hello';
     input2 = 'World';

  end

  ...

end
```